# Mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my test code which I can not figure out why it isn't working, as it is very similar to test ['populating multiple children of a sub-array at a time'](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/model.ref.test.js#L1109).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testy');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var MovieSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    tags: [OwnedTagSchema]
});

var TagSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var OwnedTagSchema = new Schema({
    _name: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'},
    _owner: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

var Tag = mongoose.model('Tag', TagSchema),
    User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema),
    Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);
    OwnedTag = mongoose.model('OwnedTag', OwnedTagSchema);

User.create({name: 'Johnny'}, function(err, johnny) {
    Tag.create({name: 'drama'}, function(err, drama) {
        Movie.create({'title': 'Dracula', tags:[{_name: drama._id, _owner: johnny._id}]}, function(movie) {

            // runs fine without 'populate'
            Movie.find({}).populate('tags._owner').run(function(err, movies) {
                console.log(movies);
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Produced error is

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'path' of undefined
    at /Users/tema/nok/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:234:44
```

**Update**

Got rid from OwnedTag and rewrote MovieSchema like this

```
var MovieSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    tags: [new Schema({
        _name: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'},
        _owner: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
    })]
});
```

Working code https://gist.github.com/1541219

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `OwnedTagSchema` must be defined before you use it or you'll end up doing basically this:

```
var MovieSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  tags: [undefined]
});
```

Move it above `MovieSchema` definition.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect your code to work, too. Does it work if you put the `OwnedTag` right in `MovieSchema`, like so?

```
var MovieSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  tags: [{
           _name: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'},
           _owner: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
        }]
});
```

edit:

```
var MovieSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  tags: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'OwnedTag' }]
});
```

Comment: Ah. Actually, go back to your original model. You're using `.populate` but you're using a subdocument for `tags`, not a ref. I don't expect it to work -- we're getting further and further from the strength of a NoSQL database -- but, maybe this would work -- see added 2nd attempt above.

Comment: This breaks everything :-( I don't get what is the difference between https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/model.ref.test.js#L1109 Maybe you can help me to see it?

Comment: Please enter the solution as a solution when you get the chance